# Getting Timeout::Error in capybara and ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I am using cucumber+capybara in my tests

```
env.rb
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
World(Capybara::DSL)
```

In my test I am clicking on a link

```
Then /^I see deals on map$/ do
  find("#dealmap").click
end
```

Above action is opening a layer (div) but the process stuck on find("#dealmap").click method. After 5 seconds I am getting following error

```
 Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rbuf_fill'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1319:in `block in transport_request'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `catch'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `transport_request'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in `request'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1286:in `block in request'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
      ./features/frontend/step_definitions/search_results_page.rb:2:in `/^I see deals on map$/'
      features/frontend/search_results_page.feature:6:in `Then I see deals on map'
```

NOTE:
I have tried with increasing time but it is not solving the problem

I am unable to resolve the issue. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Try to research existing questions referring to [Timeout::Error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcapybara%5D+timeout%3A%3Aerror)

Comment: If you have a reproducible case, report it to Capybara issue tracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problems comes from this line

```
Capybara.run_server = false
```

You will need this if you're running rack based tests. Remove it and re-run your tests.

If you're running web based tests you would want to keep this in there- and just because you're using Selenium doesn't mean you're running web bases tests. You're still running rack based tests but in a browser.